# does laravel encodes data between server and user?

Tags: laravel, security, encryption

As I think, Laravel does not include an encoding/decoding procedure for making a secure and encrypted connection between server and user. If it is the case, how we can improve our apps to have a secure connection?

Answer (score 1):

> secure and encrypted connection between server and user.

Do not overcomplicate things, just use **https**. It will take care of the confidentiality and integrity of the connection

> how we can improve our apps to have a secure connection

https will enable you to make a secure connection, but it doesn't ensure your app is secure too, you may check the [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) project

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right that there is no built encryption before sending the data from client side to server side from laravel for every request. But laravel uses [csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction) protection for security from client side to server side.

But if you wish to make such encrypted system it can easily be done manually. In order to do that you will need to encrypt your data before sending to the server side from client side. And using [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#introduction) concept you can easily decrypt every request that you are receiving.

You just need to decide your custom encryption and decryption algorithm.